# Retag suggestion: [requests] into [python-requests]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is an increasingly popular HTTP library for Python. There are a couple hundred questions about it, but they are split between two tags: [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) and [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests).

The [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) has been used most widely to refer to the Python library, but was also often used vaguely to refer to [httprequest](/questions/tagged/httprequest) (usually unnecessarily) or Facebook's [apprequests](/questions/tagged/apprequests).

(The worst offender was a Facebook feature request tagged [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)[requests](/questions/tagged/requests).)

I have removed the [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) tag from questions that were using it for other purposes. We should now pick one of the tags, and retag the posts to be consistent.

Given that "requests" is a fairly generic term, I definitely think we should go with [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests).

Any objections?

---

A lot of the mis-use of [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) was from people who didn't seem to understand what tags were, and were just entering stuff into the box at random. To deal with this I would like to see the [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) tag blacklisted. Users who start to enter it will have the more specific tags suggested; they should be able to make the sensible choice.

Blacklisting hasn't been common, <s>but I don't understand what the drawback is to using it in cases like this.</s> Oh, the UI sucks and the user isn't told it's blacklisted until the next screen, after the suggestions are gone. I guess that's a reason to avoid using it. Maybe the system will be improved eventually.

Comment: I have suggested `requests` as a synonym. You can [vote for the synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-requests/synonyms) if you have a 5+ score on answers on the tag.

Comment: And thanks for cleaning up `requests`!

Comment: I don't like the idea of a synonym of something as generic as `requests` being used for a specific library.  While it's by no means the library's fault, being that generic is going to tangle some people up on the site.  I prefer to *not* have the synonym.

Comment: @casperOne That's true. Also, a lot of the uses of `requests` were people who didn't understand tags just typing in something at random, so it's likely to continue to be misused like that. How about  blacklisting `requests` to prevent that? Anybody who starts to type it will have the more specific choices suggested to them.

Comment: SE won't even let us consider it unless we see a near-unstoppable deluge of questions with the tag coming in.  Blacklists are really heavyweight and SE avoids using them at great lengths.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @casperOne: there have been too many instances of a general tag being co-opted for some specific purpose; it never ends well.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've removed the merge/synonym suggestion.

Comment: Which usage had the most hits?  Was it the Python one?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am pretty sure that Python had the most use. (It definitely had a large majority of the recent use, but as you go back in time the library was less popular.) HTTP probably was a close second, but most of the questions weren't about HTTP requests in detail and didn't need the tag. (For example, there were several questions about handling large numbers of requests per second which were really performance questions about other parts of the application, and didn't care about the HTTP details.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've retagged all questions from [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) to [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests). I edited the [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) tag wiki to encourage users to pick a more specific tag, but that will disappear in a day when the unused tag is automatically pruned.